# Add a property to javascript array element

Tags: javascript

I have to test some code that contains the following comparison:

(I have tried to simplify the original code)

```
if (app.base.premiums[0].code === ‘1’)
```

and have created a test ‘app’ object

```
app = {
    base : {
        premiums: ['first']
    }
}
```

Which I have then tried to add a property to the first element in the array

app.base.premiums[0].code = '1';

But this does not return any value when I type

```
app.base.premiums[0].code
```

into the browser console.

How should I go about this?

Comment: premiums[0] can't be a string and an object at the same time.

Comment: yeah, this is primitive.

Comment: Javascript strings are primitives. Use the `String` object if you want it to be an object. @Nit: String is Object, but string is primitive. If you do `a = new String("foo")` you could add properties to the object a.

Comment: Hi @njzk2 could you add this as an answer with a jsfiddle?

Comment: @NicholasMurray: plalx answer covers it already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialize "app" in this way:

```
var app = {
    base : {
        premiums: [ {'code':2}]
    }
}
```

Now app.base.premiums[0].code returns 2

Comment: I was sure that I tried this before during one of my iterations of trying to get this to work, lol, thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Almost everything is an object in JS, but not primitive values which are: string, number, null, undefined, boolean.

They might look like objects because when you try to perform object-like interactions with primitives they are wrapped into their respective wrapper class.

`(1).toString()` is basically the same as `(new Number(1)).toString()`

However, as you can see, the `Number` instance is created and then discarded when auto-magic wrapping occurs.

What you can do however is create a new instance of `String` which will be retained:

```
premiums: [new String('first')]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing:    `'first'.code = '1';` Do you think that will work?

Nope. You'll need an object. So you'll have to make your `app` to this

```
app = {
    base : {
        premiums: [ {} ] // object literal
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the objects. The problem is that you are trying to set a property on a string primitive.

Use a String object instead:

```
premiums: [new String('first')]
```